# Best way to keep track of an object in a list?

Tags: java, android, oop

So I have an object **Size** that looks like this:

```
public class Size {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private boolean selected;
}
```

And then I have a list of Sizes:

```
private ArrayList<Size> sizes;
```

Now I want to keep track of which size in that list is selected. Right now I am **using the boolean attribute selected** and not sure if that is the best or cleanest way. The reason I mention that is when I select a different size **I have to iterate thru the whole list and changed selected to false unless it's the one I want**.  I feel like that is overcomplicating things and was wondering if there was a better/cleaner solution.

Comment: You can keep index of selection item.

Comment: Do you only ever have one Size selected at once?

Comment: Presumably, `sizes` is a field in one of your classes. Why not just add a `private Size selectedSize` field to that class?

Comment: Explain *HOW* the object is selected. What sort of user interface are you using to allow selection? Also what is the original source of your `Size` objects?

Comment: @pbabcdefp yes only one size is ever selected.

Comment: @Squonk I pass the list into a listview and if you click on it then it sets that size to the default.

Comment: @Claud25 : In that case, the relevant `ListView` click handler will tell you which item has been selected (by position) and all you need is to maintain that position. No need for the `boolean selected` field of the `Size` class.

Comment: @Squonk I see what you're saying. I guess I don't really feel like that is the cleanest way to maintain that position but if there isn't any other solution then I think that will work.

Comment: @Claud25 : `ListView` extends `AdapterView` which maintains the selected item position for the lifetime of the `ListView` itself even if the selected item is scrolled off-screen. At any time you can call `getSelectedItemPosition()` even if the selected item isn't visible. It's how I save selected item position for a list item (using `SharedPreferences`) so if a user closes my app, I can automatically re-select the item using `setSelection(int position)` next time they use the app.

Comment: @Squonk did not know about getSelectedItemPosition(), I'll try out your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep a reference to a separate `Size` variable?
Something like this:

```
public class Size {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private boolean selected;
}

public class example {
    private Size selectedSize;
    private ArrayList<Size> sizes;

    public example() {
        Size s1 = new Size();
        Size s2 = new Size();
        Size s3 = new Size();

        sizes.add(s1);
        sizes.add(s2);
        sizes.add(s3);

        if (someCondition == true){
            // Select s1
            selectedSize = s1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have something like this but I guess to add on to the question I also want to keep track of the sizes so it's highlighted. So when selectedSize is s2, I want to highlight s2 in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

The `Size` class is supposed to be a container for name and price (presumably).

Using it to store selection state is a violation of [**Single Responsibility Principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

---

You could use something like following.

**Selectable.java**

```
public class Selectable<E> {

    /**
     * Selects the specified element if it is possible.
     *
     * @param element the element tot be selected.
     * @return true if selection is successful, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean select(E element);

    /**
     * Returns selected element if any.
     * 
     * @return The selected element if any element is selected.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if no element is selected.
     */
    public E getSelected() throws NoSuchElementException;
}
```

**SelectableArrayList.java**

```
public class SelectableArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Selectable<E> {

    private E selected;    // Can also be implemented using an index.

    public SelectableArrayList() {
        super();
        this.selected = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean select(E element) {
        if (super.contains(element)) {
            this.selected = element;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E getSelected() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (this.selected == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No element is selected in the list.");
        } else {
            return this.selected;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Trying this out, seems to fit what I want and I was looking for something like Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep index of selection item.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reference to selected `Size`, for example in same class where you have `private ArrayList<Size> sizes;`, and update that reference every time when another `Size` has been selected.